# How to output geom_raster() to a raster image?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing quantitative image analysis, and visualizing the results with ggplot2.  The output contains one datapoint for each pixel in the original image.

`geom_raster()` nicely visualizes my data in R.  But it would be nice to output a raster *image* corresponding to the results.  That way, I could flip through several derived images using a lightweight image viewer (e.g., `feh`), and the pixels would line up perfectly.

Is there an easy way to output the pixels, and *only* the pixels, to an image file?  No legend, no axes, nothing but the pixels.  Assume my `data.frame` has columns for `row` and `col`, and the desired output resolution is also known.

Comment: If you have the image in a `sp:::raster` class, you can use `plot` and save it the old `png();dev.off()` way.

Comment: `grid.raster(..., interpolate=FALSE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jlhoward for pointing me in the right direction.  There are a few more missing ingredients -- for instance, without `labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)`, the output PNG will have white borders on the bottom and left.

I decided my solution should have two parts:

1. Craft a ggplot object to visualize my data.  (This step is the same as usual.)
2. Call a general-purpose function to take care of all the annoying details which are necessary to output that plot as a pixel-perfect PNG.

Here is one such function.

```
BorderlessPlotPng <- function(plot, ...) {
  # Write a ggplot2 plot to an image file with no borders.
  #
  # Args:
  #   plot:  A ggplot2 plot object.
  #   ...:  Arguments passed to the png() function.
  require(grid)
  png(type='cairo', antialias=NULL, units='px', ...)
  print(plot
        + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, -0.5, -0.5), 'line'),
                axis.text=element_blank(),
                axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                axis.title=element_blank(),
                legend.position='none')
        + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0))
        + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0))
        + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
        )
  dev.off()
}
```

To see it in action, here's a plot of some synthetic data.   (I made each output pixel 10 pixels wide for demonstration purposes.)

```
# Synthetic data.
width <- 64
height <- 48
d <- data.frame(row=rep(1:height, each=width),
                col=rep(1:width, height),
                x=rnorm(n=width * height))

# Construct and print the plot.
library(ggplot2)
plot <- (ggplot(data=d, aes(x=col, y=height + 1 - row, fill=x))
         + geom_raster()
         + scale_fill_gradient2()
         )
pixel_size <- 10
BorderlessPlotPng(plot,
                  filename='test.png',
                  width=width * pixel_size,
                  height=height * pixel_size)
```

Output:
[image: One possible output from running the above code.]

Of course, running with `pixel_size <- 1` would give you a 1:1 image, which you could compare to the original image by flipping back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) # for melt(...)

n <- 100
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
img <- matrix(rnorm(n^2,30,3),nc=n)
gg <- melt(data.frame(x=1:n,img),id="x")
ggplot(gg) + geom_raster(aes(x=x,y=variable,fill=value))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+   # get rid of extra space on x-axis
  guides(fill=FALSE)+                  # turn off color legend
  theme(axis.text=element_blank(),     # turn off the axis annotations
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]